# Change device path (/dev/sda) of internal hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, disk, devices

On my Ubuntu 22.04 have an internal hard drive connected via SATA. It shows as `/dev/sda`.

As I am working with various external drives such as SD cards and USB sticks, and writing scripts to format and flash those, I'm always threatened to accidentally wipe my internal disk if I'm not careful to never use `/dev/sda`, but rather `/dev/sdb`. I am well aware of ways to identify the correct device, e.g. via `/dev/disk/by-*` - but still, during rapid development there is chance that I carelessly paste and run some internet examples, which mostly use `/dev/sda`, and boom, my file systems are destroyed quite easily. Or if I test and run a script from my colleagues, who don't care and use `/dev/sda` statically.

So my question: Can I force my particular internal SATA disk to get another device path than `/dev/sd*` on Ubuntu?

Comment: The system is never ever going to be protected from an admin. So no.

Comment: `/dev/sda` or any of them can change during reboots of systems if a drive changes like leaving in a USB Flash drive or changing something in BIOS (UEFI) or moving cables around.  `/dev/sda` is never guaranteed to be the first boot drive.  For example, my 3TB backup drive is listing on my system as `/dev/sda1` but my root boot drive is listing as `/dev/sdd1`.  I would recommend fixing your scripts to properly detect the SDCards and USB sticks.

Comment: Can you not use UUIDs, or labels. I now use labels in my grub files to boot other installs. But every partition has to have an unique label. And I do find my jammy_a (installed on sda, originally) install may be on sdb drive depending on what drives are plugged in.

Comment: I thought that I had explained quite well that I am aware of how to identify devices properly (e.g. using UUIDs), so it should have been clear that my scripts don't need fixing. I'm not asking for how to identify a correct hard drive. I am looking for a way to protect my hard drive from being a victim of carelessness.

Comment: Drive path names are done at the kernel level and are not just a simple switch to change.  It would have to be recompiling the kernel to work the way that you would like it to be done.